# Changing the output of json_encode in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am outputting the data in `JSON` format from MySQL database in **controller** like this,

```
function byId(){
        $this -> load -> model('usermodel');
        $data['user'] = $this -> usermodel -> getById($this->uri->slash_segment(3));
        $this -> output -> set_content_type('application/json');
        $this -> output -> set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
```

Model:

```
function getById($id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);

        $q = $this -> db -> get();

        if ($q -> num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

    }
```

It outputs the data like this,

`{"user":[{"id":"3","firstname":"Frances","lastname":"Johnson","address":"489 Summit Lane","state":"Minnesota","country":"US","email":"fjohnson@teklist.net","phone":null,"experience":"2","designation":"Script"}]}`

But I need it like this,

`{user : {....} }`

Basically I want to get rid of square brackets.

What can I change in my code to get the intended output?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what the `Usermodell::getById` method does. From the json output it seems like you get an array back with numbered keys (like multiple rows from a database query) not a single row that you would expect. What does `var_dump($data['user'])` looks like?

Comment: Let me edit it to give you more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see an extra `[]` around the individual "user" objects is because of the `$data[]` array in the `getById()` method. You are returning an array with other arrays inside them and by default `json_encode` will convert numerically indexed arrays (starting from 0) as javascript arrays.

Now it depends what's your intent here. If you wanted to return a list of an users even if it has one element but force the list containing the individual user objects as an object in the json output you can go with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option like:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

But judging from your code, you just want to return the actual user object not a list of it, so you can either modify the `getById()` method to return the that with [`->row()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) on the db result, or you can grab the first object returned from the method with:

```
...->getById(...)[0]; // for php 5.4+
```

or

```
 reset(...->getById()); // for older versions
```

Comment: I tried using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Moreover, even if I want to return all the objects, and that too again without [], what changes I can make?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
$data['user'] = $this -> usermodel -> getById($this->uri->slash_segment(3));
```

with this

```
$data['user'] = $this -> usermodel -> getById($this->uri->slash_segment(3))[0];
```

`[{ ... }]` is an array containing a single object. `[0]` should grab the first element in that array rather than the array itself.